# LTF circuits and $AC^0$

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, boolean-algebra

Do we know if all of $AC^0$ can be captured by polynomial sized depth $2$ LTF circuits? (with or without polynomially bounded weights).

---

For any vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any number $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we define the LTF (x) gate as the function, $\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $LTF(x) =0$ if $c + \vec{w}.\vec{x} \leq 0$ or else $LTF(x) = 1$.

Comment: Personally I suggest that giving the definition of linear threshold circuits would make the question more self-contained.

Comment: I have put in the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that AC<sup>0</sup> can be captured by constant depth threshold circuits, but this hasn't been proved. In the case of small weights, perhaps existing methods suffice to rule out all of AC<sup>0</sup> being captured by depth 2 threshold circuits. See [Razborov's survey](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/helsinki.pdf) for several pointers, include exponential lower bounds for functions which, unfortunately, are beyond AC<sup>0</sup>

In the case of unbounded weights, we don't have any superpolynomial lower bounds. The best known lower bound for unrestricted depth two threshold circuits due to [Kane and Williams](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07860), is $\Omega(n^{3/2})$.

Comment: Thanks! (I have read that Kane-Williams paper) (1) Is this formally stated as a conjecture anywhere that polynomial sized polynomially bounded weight constant depth $LTF$ cannot capture $AC^0$. That would be very helpful! (2) So you think that even with unbounded weights and unboundd size constant depth LTFs cant capture all of $AC^0$? Could you kindly state your first conjecture a bit more precisely?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a conjecture being explicitly stated, though perhaps you can find such a conjecture in the literature. Presumably either a Sipser function or a "random" function in AC0 of high enough depth will be hard for constant-depth threshold circuits.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting confused by your phrase "constant-depth threshold circuits". What restrictions are you putting on the weights and the size?  Its somewhat believable that poly-sized poly-weight constant depth LTFs cant capture all of $AC^0$. But if you allow for either either size or weights or both to be unbounded then it looks very surprising if depth 2 LTF still continues to be weaker than $AC^0$. (..We already know from Allender's (FOCS 1989) result that quasi-polynomial depth 3 Majority gets all of $AC^0$..)

Comment: We are always interested in polysize circuits. Regarding weights, it's known that polysize depth-$d$ threshold circuits with arbitrary weights can be simulated by polysize depth-$d+1$ threshold circuits with polynomial weights, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes, but I guess its possible that with poly-size weight and with exponential/super-polynomial size depth 2 LTF gets all of $AC^0$. I cant see anything ruling this out and proving this is possibly not at all trivial...

Comment: A paper by Sherstov in 2008 showed that Allender's construction is optimal in a strong sense since there is a depth $3$ $AC^0$ function which is not in polynomial sized depth 2 majority or MAJ-of-LTF. (http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~sherstov/pdf/ac0majmaj.pdf). So depth 2 majority and MAJ-of-LTF are less powerful than even depth 3 AND-OR circuits. *BUT* it could still be true that  poly-sized poly-weight depth $2$ LTF gets all of $AC^0$. Can't see even that getting ruled out!